# How to insert foreign key in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I have to create 2 to 3 tables and I want to create foreign key of two tables and add into 3rd table. When I run the app data is inserted successfully but foreign key is not showing in the database table structure and table.

Here is my Database class:

```
     public static final String Tsk_id = "task_id";
   public static final String Task_Project_NAme = "project_name";
   public static final String Task_Team_Member_Name = "assign_to";
   public static final String Task_Title = "task_time";
   public static final String Task_Start_Date = "start_date";
   public static final String Task_CompletionDate = "completion_date";
   public static final String Task_CompletionTime = "completion_time";
   public static final String Task_Description = "task_description";
   public static final String Task_Status = "task_status";
   public static final String Task_Is_Active = "IsActive";
   public static final String Task_Project_id="project_id";
   public static final String Task_Team_Memmber_Id="team_member_id";

@Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub



      String CREATE_TASK_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + ASSIGN_TASK_TABLE + "("
                                + Tsk_id +" integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                                + Task_Project_NAme + " TEXT,"
                                + Task_Team_Member_Name + " TEXT,"
                                + Task_Title + " TEXT," 
                                + Task_Start_Date + " TEXT,"
                                + Task_CompletionDate + " TEXT,"
                                + Task_CompletionTime + " TEXT,"
                                + Task_Description + " TEXT,"
                                + Task_Status + " TEXT,"
                                + Task_Is_Active + " TEXT" 
                                + " FOREIGN KEY ("+Task_Project_id+") REFERENCES " +CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME+" ("+Project_id+")" 
                                + " FOREIGN KEY ("+Task_Team_Memmber_Id+") REFERENCES " +DEFINE_TEAM_MEMBER_TABLE+" ("+Team_Member_id+")";
      db.execSQL(CREATE_TASK_TABLE);

   }



public boolean insertTaskDetails(String strTask_Project_NAme,String strTask_Team_Member_Name,
                                    String strTask_Title,String strTask_Start_Date,String strTask_CompletionDat,
                                    String strTask_CompletionTime,String strTask_Description,
                                    String strTask_Status,String strTask_Is_Active)
   {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

      contentValues.put(Task_Project_NAme, strTask_Project_NAme);
      contentValues.put(Task_Team_Member_Name, strTask_Team_Member_Name);
      contentValues.put(Task_Title, strTask_Title); 
      contentValues.put(Task_Start_Date, strTask_Start_Date);
      contentValues.put(Task_CompletionDate,strTask_CompletionDat);
      contentValues.put(Task_CompletionTime,strTask_CompletionTime);
      contentValues.put(Task_Description, strTask_Description); 
      contentValues.put(Task_Status, strTask_Status);
      contentValues.put(Task_Is_Active,strTask_Is_Active);

      db.insert(ASSIGN_TASK_TABLE, null, contentValues);
      db.close();
      return true;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ " FOREIGN KEY ("+Task_Project_id+") REFERENCES " +CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME+" ("+Project_id+")"
```

for this line of code where is Task_Project_id column in the while creating the table.. please check.

You need to create a particular column to reference as foreign key.

same with this line too

```
 " FOREIGN KEY ("+Task_Team_Memmber_Id+") REFERENCES " +DEFINE_TEAM_MEMBER_TABLE+" ("+Team_Member_id+")";
```